# Icons not displaying, google chrome extension

Tags: javascript, json, google-chrome

I recently created a new extension which I'm still working on, and a thing I cant seem to get working is the extension icon, it isn't displayed in the extensions page or toolbar.
Here is my manifest file code:

```
  "manifest_version": 3,

  "name": "shrekistan",
  "description": "This extension changes everybodys pfp's to shrek",
  "version": "1",

  "host_permissions": [
    "http://meet.google.com/*"
  ],

  "icons": { "16": "icon16.png",
    "32": "icon32.png",
    "48": "icon48.png",
   "128": "icon128.png" },    
            
   "content_scripts": [
            {
              "matches": ["https://meet.google.com/*"],
              "js": ["yourmom.js"]
            }],
          
          "background" : { 
            "service.worker" : ["background.js"]} 
}
```

I tried multiple methods of adding icons from existing questions I found here (stack overflow) and none worked.
[image: extensions page screenshot]

Comment: I doubt if the path of an icon is correct, can you check if the icon is located in root directory and not in `<root>/icons/filename.png`.

Comment: Could you provide an image of your folder structure? It could be something about the image path.

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/CCFlIfg this is a link to an image of the extensions folder structure
@phucbm 
I am working on windows so I don't have a root directory

Comment: @RonKan have you been able to solve this issue? UPD: Nevermind, it was a problem with the images. Saved them in photoshop and now they're showing up.

Comment: @user2758776 can you submit an answer if you solved the issue?

Answer (score 2):

Seems to be an issue with the files. I used https://github.com/neglect-yp/chrome-extension-icon-generator to generate icons from the image, works fine.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. Turns out my png files were corrupt somehow. I saved them in PS and that fixed the issue.